# Returning a variable from an exported function (js)

Tags: javascript

I have a file titled random.js, where i export a function called fetch(), which returns an integer of either 0 or 1, assigned to the variable x.

If I console.log it here, as follows:

```
export function fetch() {
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
    console.log(x)
    //return x
}
```

And subsequently import the function into App.js, and call it there, as follows:

```
import { fetch } from "./random.js"

  function fetch2() {
    fetch()
    //console.log(x)
  }
```

It works as intended.

However, when I try to return the variable x from the function fetch() in random.js, as follows:

```
export function fetch() {
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
    //console.log(x)
    return x
}
```

and try to read the variable x using function fetch2() in App.js, as follows:

```
import { fetch } from "./random.js"

  function fetch2() {
    fetch()
    console.log(x)
  }
```

I get an error telling me: 'x' is not defined  no-undef

So how do I export the variable x from random.js, such that it is "readable" by App.js?

Comment: `x` is defined only to block of the function it's declared in, you need to assign the returned value first in the `fetch2` scope: `const x = fetch();`

Comment: Your `fetch` function returns the value of `x`, not `x` itself. In browsers, a [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) function already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

1. the `fetch` function must return a value.
2. in the `fetch2()` you declare new x an pass the value from the `fetch()` to it.

```js
export function fetch() {
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
    console.log(x)
    return x
}


import { fetch } from "./random.js"

  function fetch2() {
    let x = fetch()
    console.log(x)
  }
```